# Error writing proxy settings. (5) Access is denied. Everytime I boot my laptop

Tags: cmd.exe, proxy, windows-11

Error writing proxy settings. (5) Access is denied.

Current WinHTTP proxy settings:

```
Direct access (no proxy server).
```

[process exited with code 1]

Everytime.

I had used Autorun to delete everything I thought It was not nessesary, and I viewed Eventvw  to look at logs but i cant solve that problem.

===

ADD:

I followed ther PID of terminal and found that It's root parent was svchost, and When I deleted WpnUserService, It was gone..

Is it correct for solving that problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows Terminal opens on startup with proxy error](https://superuser.com/questions/1686316/windows-terminal-opens-on-startup-with-proxy-error)

Answer (score 0):

In Terminal > settings > Default terminal application
Select Windows Console Host

This worked for me

Comment: It's not working.